# "Проблема бережного отношения к природе" и "Почему важно бережно относиться к природе?" - одно и то же?

Tags: untagged

Нужен ответ от эксперта.
Допустим, есть текст, в котором сформулирована такая проблема:

> Проблема бережного отношения к природе

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в виде вопроса она будет звучать так:

> Почему важно бережно относиться к природе?

Соответственно, если так, то скажите, уместно ли брать такие примеры-аргументы из авторского текста (примеры-иллюстрации), которые показывают одно и то же, но с разных ракурсов, то есть:

- беречь природу надо, т. к ее ресурсы (вода и т.д.) дали возможность человеку жить.
- если не беречь природу, то могут могут исчезать животные и т.д.

Или же все аргументы должны быть "односторонними"?

Comment: Ну давайте немного позанимаемся буквоедством (а в реальных текстах пишите как хотите, главное чтобы понимали). Проблема это задача. Задача формулирует вопрос, на который трудно ответить, Нетривиальный вопрос. "Почему важно" это вопрос тривиальный, он не может быть реальной задачей. Но в тексте, чтобы лить воду, перечисляя всевозможные аргументы можно это сформулировать как проблему и далее её мотивировать. Реальная же проблема умещается в одно предложение "Что и как надо сделать, чтобы сохранить природу?". А дальше уже следует "решение проблемы"

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем. "Почему?" - это вопрос к предикату. А утверждение исходит из предикативной посылки: К каким проблемам приведет НЕ бережное отношение к природе? Проблема, видимо, это контр утверждение к предикативной посылке("бережное отношение к"). А "почему?" это вообще почему важно бережно относиться - то есть по какой причине, выбрано что отношение должно быть бережным. Ответы на вопросы почему могут быть самыми разными, смотря то, что вы выберете в качестве причины. Например: Бог сказал так, Природой так задумано, чтобы сохранить биологическую жизнь(не только человека), а человек является частью биосферы. Кроме того негативная аргументация по сути на вопрос "почему?" не отвечает. Ну лоси ушли из леса, померли - и что? Так как "почему?" - вопрос именно к предикату, то нужно какое-то иное позитивное утверждение, которое будет причиной существования предиката, негативные формулировки не годятся.

"Проблема" же, это акцент на негативном, то есть "какой повод?", "какой резон?" "какая выгода от?". И тут можно отвечать или негативно: животные померли, - или позитивно: жить стало еще лучше, хотя скорее не хуже. Потому что бережное - это консервативное, а консервы - это отложенное старение, без каких-то моментов рискованного развития. Бережное от беречь, то есть оберегать, то есть от берег - ограничивать, сохранять. Ограничивать можно как негативные, разрушающие факторы, так и факторы преобразования, которые могут иметь негативное влияние на объект воздействия.

"Почему?" - вопрос более общий, вопрос к предикату и ответы на него должны содержать утверждение в позитивной форме, негативных аргументов не достаточно.

"Проблема?" - посылка, исходящая из предикативного утверждения: "природу нужно сохранять/охранять/беречь", - аргументация будет исходить из негативных посылок, которые могут нанести вред экосистеме. Формулировки аргументов развития, позитивных моментов по сути к проблемам отношения не имеют, либо нужно будет переформулировать проблему, любое изменение создает риски - проблемы.